# Download a zip file from PHP readfile() in Java

Tags: java, php, download, zip

I want to download a zip file using Java via HTTP and PHP. I need this because I need the PHP to do some authorisation before I let the user download.

When authorisation succeeds, the page sends the file using this code:

```
if(file_exists($filename)){

    //Use Content-Disposition: attachment to specify the filename
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));

    //No cache
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');

    //Define file size
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo "DOWNLOAD_START\r\n";
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
}else{
    clearstatcache();
    echo "No download available.";
}
```

The download works fine when downloading via browser. I verify if it works fine by simplying attempting to extract it. The Java application produces a corrupted version.

Because the page outputs header infomation as well, I echo the "DOWNLOAD_START\r\n" to signify when the zip file starts. The code which downloads the ZIP file is:

```
InputStream sockin = keygenSock.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sockin));
System.out.println("Reading...");
for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()){
    System.out.println(line);
    if(line.startsWith("DOWNLOAD_START")){
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("contents.zip")));
        int read;
        int size = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        while((read = sockin.read(buffer, 0, 2048)) >= 0){
            size += read;
            bos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        System.out.println("SIZE READ: " + size);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        //zip(sockin);
        break;
    }
}
```

The actual bytes read is not equal to the actual file size in bytes. So I'm guessing that there is an error in the way I'm downloading the ZIP file?

How can I make the Java client download a zip file from the page after authorisation?

Again, the error is that the ZIP file downloaded is smaller than the actual ZIP file.

Thanks.

EDIT: If I just dump **all** of the output into the zip file, I am able to extract it using winRAR. However if I open it up in a text editor, I can see all the header information and "DOWNLOAD_START" before the actual zip file. This causes the Java unzip classes (ZipInputStream and ZipEntry) to fail so I will need to not include those even if it does extract correctly using software like winRAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the BufferedReader, it will read/consume more than just the single line from the stream.

So either use an unbuffered reader. Meaning you have no readline method.

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
int character;
while ((character = reader.read()) >= 0 && character != '\n') {
    line.append(character);
}
```

Or just use do the same thing with the InputStream.

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
int character;
while ((character = stream.read()) >= 0 && character != '\n') {
    line.append(character);
}
```

Both lines will contain the \r if it was present (so change your code accordingly). As long as the used encoding does not mess with the lower 127 bytes you should be fine either way.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that about BufferedReader and I can work with unbuffered streams.